# Calculation of rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> If $A=(a_{ij})$ is a ${n \times n}$ matrix such that $\forall i,j$  ,$a_{ij}=2i+3j$ then what is the rank of $A$?

I tried this problem but I'm getting nowhere. Is there any direct (or indirect) method to calculate the rank of $A$? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: What's the difference between consecutive rows (or consecutive columns)? So how many rows (columns) do you need in addition to the first one to generate all the others?

Comment: @Sayantan: You're welcome.